# Why ACF relationship field in repeater returns an array with an object and not an object

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF group with repeater named "cards", which has relationship field inside.
[image: Field group with repeater]

The relationship field is set to return a post object. When I output this repeater, I get an array with 1 element, and not an object itself.
So this

```
<?php
$cards = get_field('cards');

if ($cards): ?>

    <?php
    while (have_rows('cards')): the_row();
        $link_card = get_sub_field('link_card');
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($link_card);
        echo '</pre>';
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

gives me an array like this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#2638 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(42)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ....
    }
}
```

As a result, I can't access any data until I choose $link_card[0]. For example,

```
get_the_title( $link_card[0]->ID );
```

will give me the result. Please, explain to me, why does the relationship field that should return the post object returns an array with that post object? Of course I can use that $link_card[0] but I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Thats because you are also able to select more than one in a relationship.. Basically you have to use `foreach( $link_card as $single_link_card ):` inside your while loop.

Comment: @Stender you're right; I saw this in code examples but didn't connect two dots. Thanks!